# Is the May 2017 contract creation attack still possible?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, gas, security, attacks

In May 2017, an "attacker" created a contract that attempts to create many other contracts(using many JUMPDEST operations in the creation bytecode) until it runs out of gas.

I see the gas improvemnts of EIP-150, but don't see where this attack would be mitigated today.

Is this "attack" still possible?

[One of the txs](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc1f1517f0af330995769eeb458de995a486a3137e2560bc2c56c70ceb8623574)

[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6epy1q/your_attacker_and_how_to_stop_them/)

Comment: After reading the Reddit thread I still don't understand the attack vector. Who gains and how?

Comment: I believe it was an attempted DoS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this reddit message it was fixed in geth 1.6.5 https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6ene3u/the_attacker_is_back_account_related_to_devcon2/

Pull request with the fix: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/14570

> core/vm: Use a bitmap instead of a map for jumpdest analysis